# How return empty expression?

Tags: c#, linq, iqueryable

I need return empty filter (non filter) if filter.Operator equal 'override'.
How to do this?

```
Func<IQueryable<T>, KendoFilterDescription, IQueryable<T>> appendFilter =
    (filteredData, filter) =>
    {
        if (filter.Operator == "override")
        {
            return filteredData;
        }
        return filteredData.Where(ConvertToWhereStatement(filter), 
                                    ParsePropertyValue<T>(filter));
    };
```

Comment: Empty Filter means ??

Comment: are you referring to NULL ?

Comment: Please, we need that you provide more information about your problem. It seems that my interpretation of your question is totally wrong. Ouch!

Comment: I don't understand the question either

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are talking about of an *empty filter*, I understand that you need to return a `IQueryable<T>` value that contains no data.

If so, you can use a helper method to obtain an empty `IEnumerable<T>` collection.

```
private IEnumerable<T> GetEmptyIEnumerableCollectionHelper()
{
    yield break;
}
```

This helper method allows you to populate an empty collection. Then, using `AsQueryable()` method you obtain a `IQueryable<T>`.

```
return this.GetEmptyIEnumerableCollectionHelper().AsQueryable();
```

Comment: but just `.AsQueryable();` helped me